Quarkus @ApplicationScoped and @Scheduled with @UnlessBuildProperty
I have a service class like so :
@UnlessBuildProperty(name = "someservice.enabled", stringValue = "false")
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeService{

  @Scheduled(every = "${check.interval:1M}")
  public void process() {
     //do something
  }
}

The intention is that the service class should not be instantiated at all in case the build property someservice.enabled is false . And if not specified or true the service should be instantiated and the scheduled method in the service should execute every 1 minute.
However with the @UnlessBuildProperty either the class is never instantiated or the scheduled method never executes.
Only when I comment out the above annotation does it work. What am I doing wrong ? And how should I fix this ?

Update : the above code sample works.
However, the key thing to note is that by default if the property is absent the UnlessBuildProperty is treated as false.
You also need to add the property explicitly to your application.properties.
I did have a config like below and did not work. But adding the property explicitly to application.properties works.
This does not work

@ConfigMapping(prefix = "someservice")
public interface SomeServiceConfig {
 @WithName("enabled")
  @WithDefault("true")
  Optional<Boolean> enabled();
}

Discussion from : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/39994
